# How to record(reverse-engineer) PCI transactions on Linux

Tags: linux, driver, reverse-engineering, device-driver, pci-bus

I want to record all read/write PCI transactions of a device driver. Is there a way to do it by a linux command or on software?

Comment: You mean Applicaiton<--> Driver Or Driver<-->Hardware ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Memory-mapped I/O Trace](http://lwn.net/Articles/270939/) is now in the mainline kernel, see [/usr/src/linux/Documentation/trace/mmiotrace.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/mmiotrace.txt) for documentation.

Comment: This is useful for logging access to the memory-mapped portion of the PCI device, but does not log access to the device's PCI configuration (eg. setting BARs). You can google and find that a full analysis can be done with qemu's tracer, but I've yet to find the native solution.